# I want to install pyOpt for python, but pyopt is already installed and pip is case insensitive

Tags: python, module, pip

I'm new to this forum and relatively new to python. The problem I'm having is a follows: I'm trying to install the module pyOpt(the optimization package) but when I use my ide's command line and pip install it says that the package is already installed. However, the package that is currently installed is pyopt. I've only ever used pip install and from what I've been able to gather it is case insensitive and thinks that pyOpt is pyopt. I don't really know where to go from here, and thought you guys might have some suggestions.

PS. my ide is enthought canopy

Comment: Are you sure that pyOpt *isn't* pyopt?

Comment: Which IDE are you using.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately. pyopt doesn't have the same methods as pyOpt is supposed to. and I've looked at the folders in the pyOpt zip on my desktop and they don't match the files for pyopt.

Comment: I'm using Canopy as my IDE

Answer (score 2):

[pyopt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyopt/0.84) is not [pyOpt](http://www.pyopt.org/). In fact, pyOpt is not on pypi, so you have to download it separately and install e.g. with setup.py. Depending on your system it might be available through the package management system.